# I am trying to implement binary search but i dont know whats wrong with my code?

Tags: python

This is binary search algorithm that is showing output as None. I dont know why. And if you know any free course to learn data sctrucures and algorithm in python please let me know .

```
import random

def binary_search(list,target):
  start_index=0
  end_index=len(list)-1
  while start_index<=end_index:
    midpoint=(start_index+end_index)//2
    midpoint_value=list[midpoint]
    if midpoint_value==target:
      return midpoint+1
    elif midpoint_value<target:
      end_index=midpoint-1
    else:
      start_index=midpoint+1

print(binary_search([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],8))
```

8 on 7th index position

Comment: work through your control flow with pen and paper.  Hint: what does the fn return if it doesn't find the desired value? [this should also show you your bug]

Comment: separately, don't call lists `list`

Comment: Before learning data structures, learn how to use a debugger. Preferably, find yourself a video tutorial based on the IDE you're using. Finding mistakes in code is much easier if you can step through it and inspect its state.

Answer (score 0):

You're using < wrong. It should be >

```py
def binary_search(list, target):
    start_index = 0
    end_index = len(list)-1
    while start_index <= end_index:
        midpoint = (start_index+end_index)//2
        midpoint_value = list[midpoint]
        if midpoint_value == target:
            return midpoint+1
        elif midpoint_value > target:
            end_index = midpoint-1
        else:
            start_index = midpoint+1

print(binary_search([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 8))
```

More appropriate approach will be to return True/False to compare later

```py
def binary_search(list, target):
    start_index = 0
    end_index = len(list)-1
    while start_index <= end_index:
        midpoint = (start_index+end_index)//2
        midpoint_value = list[midpoint]
        if midpoint_value == target:
            return True
        elif midpoint_value > target:
            end_index = midpoint-1
        else:
            start_index = midpoint+1
    return False

print(binary_search([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 8))
```

[Binary Search](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-binary-search/) reference.

[G4G](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/courses/Python-Foundation?utm_source=geeksforgeeks&utm_medium=submenu_22&utm_campaign=courses-submenu) is a great resource for learning.